# How to get a string dump of an executable?

Tags: regex, string, file, logic, executable

I'm working on a project and i need to get a list of all strings contained in a executable PE file, like some programs do. Here is a screenshot of what i need that the file returns:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/badC9.png

I can have the HEX dump of the file, and the strings are there, but i don't know how to extract them. Maybe with regex or something, idk...

I don't want the code, just the logic of the code. Thanks!

Any tips about this?

Answer (score 1):

On linux computers there is a command "strings" (part of binutils package):
*strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.*

If you have [cygwin](https://cygwin.com) installed on a windows computer, you could use that command from the cygwin command line:

`strings /cygdrive/h:/.../executablefile`